# Trying to write code that won't do anything until it is a certain time of day, but I get error message "Exceeded maximum stack depth"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This is my code:

```js
var d = new Date();

function myFunction() {
  
  ifNewDay();
  
}

function ifNewDay() {
  var currentTime = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    if(currentTime == "3:21:00:00 AM EDT"){
      Logger.log("It is 3:21 PM");
    } else {
      ifNewDay();
    }
}
```

I am trying to write code that will only continue once it hits a certain time, I'm sure there's a way easier way to do this, but I'm brand new. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a limit on how deep you can recurse, and in you case, that's A LOT of calls in a short period.

When you call a function it gets added to the stack in memory, and there's a limit on how big the stack can be. You can read more [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-recursion-call-stack) about how it works.

You could use [sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep) and call that function only every second or so, or at least half a second or something.

Comment: Ahh, I had a hunch it had to do with recursing. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No problemo! Btw, I'm not sure what you are using this for, but usually setting up some scheduled task in the system is a better way of doing something periodical like this, instead of checking if it's the time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like using a time driving trigger is what would work best. Have you looked into triggers?
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable