# Exceeded maximum stack depth

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

When opening the web app I get Exceeded maximum stack depth, randomly. After a bit it goes away.

Sometimes switching between exec and dev solves it. But most of the times it wont. Also the Issue happens on one app and a copy of the same app doesn't get the issue.

Could It be a problem with google script itself?
The app I'm running is pretty intensive, but between it working fine and receiving this error, no code has been changed.

Comment: Which web app are you opening?

Comment: Take a look at the execution log and see if you can pin down a certain area of the code that fails the most.  Then try to streamline/debug that code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to write code that won't do anything until it is a certain time of day, but I get error message "Exceeded maximum stack depth"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43441221/trying-to-write-code-that-wont-do-anything-until-it-is-a-certain-time-of-day-b)